# Stuck trying to assign JS vars to hidden fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've been fighting with this for a couple of days now...need some guidance please.

I have pared down a much bigger form to a "sample" size to demonstrate what I am after.
The area in question is blocked off in a very recognizable area in the calcFees function.

I also tried to get fancy and have the vars self post to the form so they could be seen, but that does not work.

UPDATE: Here is a bit more info as to what I am running into.

```
//At this point the var regularfee is = 26.5
// (confirmed by console.log(regularfee);)
// I want to assign it to the hidden field with the id="regularfee"
// I have tried both of the following lines:
document.getElementById('regularfee').value=regularfee.value;
// console.log(document.getElementById('regularfee.value')); shows "null"
document.getElementById('regularfee').value=regularfee;
// console.log(document.getElementById('regularfee')); shows "[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

What am I doing wrong?

END OF UPDATE *****************************************************

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="multiForm" action="post.php" method="POST" id="app" name="app">
<div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">

Name: <input type="text" size="40" name="name1" >
<br><br>

<table border="1" cellpadding="5" width="50%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="3"><strong>Membership Classification</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr><td width="1000">
<input name="paymethod" type="radio" class="pay" id="paypal" value="paypal" />I would like to use PayPal &#160;&#160;
<input name="paymethod" type="radio" class="pay" id="check" value="check" />I would like to pay by check
</td>
<td style="width:150px" align="right">Fee
</td>

<td style="width:150px">

</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="memberclass" type="radio" class="membership" id="regular" value="regular"/>     Regular Membership</td>

<td align="right"><div id=regularfee></td>
<td><div align="right" id=regselectedfee></td>

</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="right">Total </td>
<td><div align="right" id=total>

</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

<input type="hidden" name="regularfee" id="regularfee" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="regselectedfee" id="regselectedfee" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="">

</form>
<br>
<input type="button" id="C1" value="Continue" onClick="showLayer('page2')">
</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">
<b>Page 2

<br><br>

<input type="button" id="B1" value="Go Back" onClick="showLayer('page1')">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click to see Vars" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

var paypalselected
var checkselected
var regularfee
var memberfee1
var total

$(function () {

function clearForm()
{
     paypalselected = "0";
     checkselected = "0";
     regularfee = 0.0;
     memberfee1 = 0.0;
     total = 0.0;
     $("#regselectedfee").text(memberfee1.toFixed(2));
     $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2));

    // clear all radio buttons

    $("#regular").prop("checked", false );
}

function calcFees()
{
     total = (memberfee1);
     $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2));

// **********************************************************************************
// Here is where I want to plug in the 3 JS vars to the hidden fields
// regularfee, regselectedfee, total
// Here is what I've tried:
// vars are not getting plugged in
// If possible, I would like the vars to be plugged in dynamically 
// just as the form is updateddynamically when user selects buttons

document.getElementById('regularfee').value=regularfee;
document.getElementById('regselectedfee').value=regselectedfee;
document.getElementById('total').value=total;
// **********************************************************************************

}

function selectPayment()
{
    $(".pay").change(function () {
        clearForm();
        if ($("#paypal").prop("checked")) {

            regularfee = 26.50;
            $("#regularfee").text(regularfee.toFixed(2));
            paypalselected = "1";
            checkselected = "0";
         }
       if ($("#check").prop("checked")) {

            regularfee = 25.0;
            $("#regularfee").text(regularfee.toFixed(2));
            checkselected = "1";
            paypalselected = "0";
           }
      });
}

clearForm();

selectPayment();

//start of membership button selection

    $(".membership").change(function () {
     if (paypalselected == "1"){
        if ($("#regular").prop("checked")) {
            memberfee1 = 26.5;
            $("#regselectedfee").text(memberfee1.toFixed(2));
            calcFees();
            } 
         } //end of paypalselected test

      if (checkselected == "1"){
        if ($("#regular").prop("checked")) {
            memberfee1 = 25.0;
            $("#regselectedfee").text(memberfee1.toFixed(2));
            calcFees();
            } 
        } //end of checkselected test

      }); //end of $(".membership").change(function () {

});
//end of main function

var currentLayer = 'page1';
function showLayer(lyr){
    hideLayer(currentLayer);
document.getElementById(lyr).style.visibility = 'visible';
currentLayer = lyr;
window.scrollTo(0,0);
}

function hideLayer(lyr){
document.getElementById(lyr).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>

<style>
body{
font: 10pt sans-serif;
}
.page{
position: absolute;
top: 10;
left: 100;
visibility: hidden;
}

p.small
{
line-height: 5px;
}

p.smalltext12
{
font-size:12px
}
</style>
```

Comment: **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/3wtVd/)** As you can see from the highlighting, the HTML is invalid.

Comment: What's the problem? You want hidden fields? Don't want hidden fields? Can't find JS vars? I don't get it. Form thingie seems to work: `0`, `25` or `26.5` as total. Is that good?

Comment: the vars are not getting plugged into the hidden fields

Comment: I looked at the JSFiddle...the JSFiddle form does not display any values for me when I click buttons. The code as posted does work for me. My only issue is getting the hidden fields populated

Comment: What you are doing wrong is using the same id `total` in 2 places. Make these ids (and any others) unique and you should have better luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 elements `#total`. Only the first is given a value:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
```

Same for the others.

IDs must be unique to be useful.

Comment: No...look closer.  The first "$("#total").text(total.toFixed(2));" is part of the clearForm() function.  Just above you will see that total is being set to 0.  The second is part of calcFees().  As I said...I am not having trouble with the logic or calculations/display of the form...the question is strictly regarding the assignment of vars into the hidden fields.

Comment: @user3066388 Uh.. yes you do.  You have two elements with the id of total.  That is invalid html, and is probably why your script isn't working; it will only assign values to the first element.. if you want to assign to groups of elements, use classes.  On top of that, your other elements ids are duplicated too, so this answer should solve your problems if you follow it. _IDs must be unique_.

Comment: @Daedalus - Sorry...I think I had a HIGH degree of tunnel vision on this one!  I was so focused on my problem being right there where I was trying to assign the hidden elements that I wasn't really entertaining the idea that it could have been something as simple as this.  Many thanks!  I have not had time to make the changes yet but this is an obvious problem that probably will solve my issues.  Thanks again!